# ユーザーeditでNo route matches [PATCH] "/users/7/edit"になってしまいます

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初めての質問なので説明不足などあるかもと思うのですが、アドバイスお願いします。

railsチュートリアルベースでプログラム組んでいて、４章と９章を飛ばしてしまっているのですが、一応１０章まで組んで、その上にオリジナルのプログラムを乗っけている感じです。

本題なのですが作成したユーザーのeditをsaveしようとすると `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/7/edit"` というエラーが出てしまいます。

---

edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit user') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_fome.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:url)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/unity', to: 'static_pages#unity'
  resources :users

  # Place リソースのルーティング
  resources :places
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @places = @user.place.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
      # 更新に成功した場合を扱う。
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
  end

  # beforeアクション

  # 正しいユーザーかどうか確認
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

  # 管理者かどうか確認
  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

現在のルーティング出力

```
$ bundle exec rake routes

  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
  sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)    sessions#new
  users_new    GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
  root         GET    /                          static_pages#home
  help         GET    /help(.:format)            static_pages#help
  about        GET    /about(.:format)           static_pages#about
  contact      GET    /contact(.:format)         static_pages#contact
  unity        GET    /unity(.:format)           static_pages#unity
  signup       GET    /signup(.:format)          users#new
               POST   /signup(.:format)          users#create
  edit         GET    /edit(.:format)            users#edit
  login        GET    /login(.:format)           sessions#new
               POST   /login(.:format)           sessions#create
  logout       DELETE /logout(.:format)          sessions#destroy
  users        GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
  new_user     GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
  edit_user    GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
  user         GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
  places       GET    /places(.:format)          places#index
               POST   /places(.:format)          places#create
  new_place    GET    /places/new(.:format)      places#new
  edit_place   GET    /places/:id/edit(.:format) places#edit
  place        GET    /places/:id(.:format)      places#show
               PATCH  /places/:id(.:format)      places#update
               PUT    /places/:id(.:format)      places#update
               DELETE /places/:id(.:format)      places#destroy
```

Comment: `bundle exec rake routes` を実行すると、何が出力されますか？

Comment: 現在のルーティングが出力されているんだと思いますが、そのような表示が出ました

Comment: その結果を、質問に追記していただけますか？

Answer (score 0):

自己解決できました。
_fome.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: yield(:url)) do |f| %>
```

を　↓

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: user_path) do |f| %>
```

に変換したら通りました。

参考にしたリンクは↓です。
https://teratail.com/questions/66002

相談に乗ってくれた方へ、ありがとうございました。